# 24" Base Cabinet for Sink vs. 30" Base Sink Cabinet?

Tags: cabinets, custom-cabinetry

I have a 72" opening for a kitchenette in an office space.

I am trying to not custom order cabinets due to budget constraints and am considering using the Home Depot in-house brands (I used them before on a flip house and they were "okay" for the price, please no flame wars on Ikea vs. HD please...).

For this 72" opening, I would like to have a 24" fridge, 24" sink base cabinet, and 24" dishwasher (so 72" used).

However.... Home Depot only has a 30" and 36" sink base cabinet in the slab finish they stock.   They do however, make a  24" base cabinet which is not marketed as holding a sink, but looks like two doors, and is open on the inside.

Here is a link:

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-Designer-Series-Edgeley-Assembled-24x34-5x23-75-in-Full-Height-Door-Base-Kitchen-Cabinet-in-White-BF24-EDWH/305842562

If you took a 24" base cabinet (not the "sink base"), would this work for for bar sized undermount sink?   Like I see the doors are going to be like 1/4" from the top of the countertop.   The sink base has shorter doors, and you have this weird clearance door issue.

Solution #2 is use the 36" sink base, and then 18" fridge, and 18" dishwasher.

(Technically we have 2 kitchenettes with this same problem...  Custom cabinets, are $11,000 [very nice Yorktowne cabinets which I have in my house already, very nice stuff!].  The HD solution, if you could stomach the 24" base cabinet - $2,000....)

Comment: and what is the question ?

Comment: Can you put in a bar sink in this 24" cabinet?  Besides internal clearance for the plumbing, what else is different from a "sink base" cabinet?   On all l the sink base cabinets, they have like a 6" top piece, and then the doors.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that should work fine. There is really only one special thing about a "sink cabinet":

- No drawer at the top.

Which usually means a fake drawer front. This cabinet instead has doors the full height, which is perfectly fine. In fact, in your case, since the other two 24" sections are refrigerator and dishwasher, there aren't even any other cabinets *with* drawers for a fake drawer front to match.

FYI, the same thing is often done, *unnecessarily*, for a cooktop. But many modern cooktops are so shallow that a drawer is perfectly fine as long as you can hack the drawer to allow for power and/or gas connections. But I digress.

As far as width, 24" is a little on the narrow side, which is why they are not even offering a sink cabinet in 24" width. For a typical drop-in stainless steel sink, the overall width is 25" and the internal (bowl) width is about 21" - which is a *very* tight fit for a 24" cabinet. (Been there, done that, though fortunately not with my own kitchen.)

However, bar sinks are readily available in smaller sizes. Plenty of 15" sinks available at Home Depot (and other places) and any of those should work fine in a 24" cabinet.

I would definitely go for a smaller sink rather than a smaller refrigerator (really limits you if you want to stock up for a party) or a smaller dishwasher (smaller dishwashers tend to cost more than full-size dishwashers). The only problem will be when it comes to scrubbing big pots and pans.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  I just want to sanity check if I missing something besides the fake drawer front.  The kitchen designer, proposed the 3 x 24's with $11,000 of cabinets, and I'm really having a hard time seeing the ROI in this commercial space [my own industrial condo].   The bar sink totally works for what is needed; ie. clean a plate or mug, no pots or pans in the kitchenettes.   The 36" sink base, with 18" dishwasher, and 18" fridge feels real sad...  The 18" fridge can't hold anything!

Comment: The best was Mill's Pride. It was a Home Depot brand like Ryobi - i.e., another company supplying Home Depot with private label stuff. Built my kitchen out of it early 2000. Flat pack but really sturdy, you could get almost anything (from full height pantry cabinets to base cabinets, upper cabinets, various door styles, etc.) in every Home Depot store in stock, and for the few special things I needed I built them myself from matching white melamine. The price was incredible. And some of the Home Depots (not all, but an hour away, not too bad) had a countertop shop so I was able to get

Comment: Wilsonart (like Formica) counters custom cut with sink and cooktop cutouts and then put it all together myself (with some help from relatives). Unfortunately Mill's Pride went out of business many years ago and Home Depot never got a replacement.

Comment: Really all you need is one 24" base (for your sink) + a 48" counter with a sink hole cut in it + sink + faucet + dishwasher and you're done. Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Interesting!  I had some medium grade "Martha Stewart" line of custom cabs from Home Depot, and I thought for the price at the time they were quite good.   I had a vacation house with the raised panel / straight outta the store / Hampton Bay white specials -- I'll tell you what, for the cost.... I had no complaints with them.   Are they the world's nicest cabinets, no... but for what you get.  I really was impressed.  I have a countertop guy who did our house, but I may let HD do the countertops since these are pretty small runs.

Comment: I'm gonna have 3 24" uppers, and a mini 24" fridge, but yes,  wizz bang 72" run, drop in the base cabinets and off you go.   We talked about a full 24" fridge to replace the 24" base and 24" upper;  but the space is truly 72": wide so the fridge door is gonna be a litlte cumbersome with a full 24" fridge.  I super appreciate the go ahead on the base cab issue.

Comment: The key on countertops is to make sure they do it right! I ordered in the store. Normal time = 1 week. Came back 1 week later. Looked at one of the pieces and thought it didn't seem quite right. Measured it. It was a few inches off in one cut (don't remember the specifics) - they confirmed it didn't match the order. They cut a new piece right away on the spot (can't beat that) and then I hit the road. And the van broke down...which was another story...but I'm using the same kitchen and counters 22 years later.

Answer (score 2):

What you propose is exactly what I did in my laundry room.  I used the Hampton Bay pre-assembled satin white shaker 24" base and made the following modifications:

(These modifications were specific to my cabinet which had a drawer above the door)

- Remove the drawer box and drawer slides to provide clearance for the sink.
- Remove the drawer front from the box and attach to the face frame with brackets I made from scrap.
- Dropped on the countertop with sink.

Since your cabinet has doors that take up the entire vertical height of the cabinet, you will not even need the false drawer front.

Aside from that difference, the cabinets appear identical.  Other than the drawer and one small extra cross brace at the back (which you can easily add in the field), there was no difference between that 24" base and the 36" sink base cabinet I bought for the kitchen.

Comment: Sounds like you had a different base. The base OP references just has doors, no drawer. What you described works for a cabinet with a drawer to make it a false drawer.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact You're right.  In that case, it's even easier.  Will edit to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for the info.   I'm waiting on the HD designer to work up the order;  they measured last week!